# unnest() doesn't work with list columns any more

Tags: r, dplyr, unnest

You can comfortably create nested models with map() resulting in list columns:

```
df <- mtcars %>% 
  nest(data = -c(cyl)) %>% 
  mutate(aov  = map(data, ~ aov(mpg ~ hp, data = .x))) %>% 
  mutate(dunned = map(data, ~ rstatix::dunn_test(mpg ~ hp, data = .x)))


df
# A tibble: 3 × 4
    cyl data               aov    dunned                 
  <dbl> <list>             <list> <list>                 
1     6 <tibble [7 × 10]>  <aov>  <rstatix_test [6 × 9]> 
2     4 <tibble [11 × 10]> <aov>  <rstatix_test [45 × 9]>
3     8 <tibble [14 × 10]> <aov>  <rstatix_test [36 × 9]>
```

However, desolving these list columns by unnest() works only sometimes, e.g. here:

```
df %>% unnest(dunned)
# A tibble: 87 × 12
     cyl data     aov   .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic      p
   <dbl> <list>   <lis> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     6 <tibble… <aov> mpg   105    110        1     3     1.62  0.106 
 2     6 <tibble… <aov> mpg   105    123        1     2     0     1     
 3     6 <tibble… <aov> mpg   105    175        1     1     0.661 0.509
```

However, it doesn't work in other cases:

```
df %>% unnest(aov) # Error: Input must be a vector, not a <aov/lm> object.
df %>% unnest_wider(aov) # Error: Input must be list of vectors
df %>% unnest_legacy(aov) # Error: Each column must either be a list of vectors or a list of data frames [lm]
```

Before tidier 1.0, the unnest() would work on the above objects, but now it doesn't (see unnest_legacy(aov)). Why?
My guess is it depends on the output format (e.g. if it is a dataframe, denoted by `[6 × 9]`), so these cases are no problem.

#### Question:

How can you desolve list columns (created by common models such as `aov` and `lm`) for which none of the `unnest/unnest_wider/unnest_legacy` options work?

#### Expected Result:

I'm looking for a solution which is more general than a "trick" I know for the aov case:

```
df <- mtcars %>% 
  nest(data = -c(cyl)) %>% 
  mutate(aov  = map(data, ~ aov(mpg ~ hp, data = .x))) %>% 
  mutate(tidied = map(aov, ~ broom::tidy(.x)))
```

which unfolds easily:

```
df %>% unnest(tidied)
# A tibble: 6 × 9
    cyl data     aov    term     df   sumsq meansq statistic
  <dbl> <list>   <list> <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
1     6 <tibble… <aov>  hp        1   0.205  0.205    0.0821
2     6 <tibble… <aov>  Resi…     5  12.5    2.49    NA     
3     4 <tibble… <aov>  hp        1  55.7   55.7      3.40  
4     4 <tibble… <aov>  Resi…     9 148.    16.4     NA
```

Comment: what is your desired output? How would an unnested version of an `aov` object look like

Comment: exactly like the output for `df %>% unnest(dunned)`, only for the aov output.

Comment: Do you want `map(data, ~ broom::tidy(aov(mpg ~ hp, data = .x)))`? (instead of your current map call)

Comment: but `dunned` is a data.frame-like object so it is clear what the outcome would look like. `aov` is a huge list (see e.g. `str(df$aov[[1]])`) which contains all fitted values, residuals, coefficient etc. So it is not clear what the output should look like.

Comment: @Cett I added the expected result.

Comment: @moodymudskipper funny, that's exactly what i added in the expected result! yes, that's good, but would it work for any other model?

Comment: Probably, if not you might try `map(data, ~ as_tibble(map(aov(mpg ~ hp, data = .x), list)))`, or `map(data, ~ enframe(unclass(aov(mpg ~ hp, data = .x))))`

Comment: @moodymudskipper these are cool suggestions, thanks a lot!! i will try them out on other models. But please also submit them as solution, maybe others confirm that they work more generally.

Comment: @moodymudskipper i tried them on `mtcars %>%  nest(data = -c(cyl))` but they didn't work. but thanks for the inspirations.

Comment: They don't give the same output as broom::tidy, but they take all the information in the object and put it in a form you can unnest, and this should be general enough to work on any list like named object. I would just use `broom::tidy()` though